# How to range the cells of the results along the horizontal direction and some of the parameters of the formula along vertical direction?

Tags: excel, vba

This is a job for my university, and I am trying to automate the process using Macro-VBA, which I am quite interested in learning for professional objectives

Actually, it was not possible to try too many things because I am a beginner using Excel-VBA; so my skills are quite narrow.

```
Sub kt()
'
' kt Macro
'

'
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = _
        "=Série_B!R[16]C[-1]*'Hélices_0 - Teste'!R4C7^Série_B!R[16]C*'Hélices_0 - Teste'!R4C6^Série_B!R[16]C[1]*'Hélices_0 - Teste'!R4C5^Série_B!R[16]C[2]*'Hélices_0 - Teste'!R4C2^Série_B!R[16]C[3]"

    ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Select
End Sub
```

The results cell is heading in the row direction. Meanwhile, I was expecting the parameters referred to "Série_B!" spreadsheet ranging in the column direction, but actually they are changing of columns instead of changing of rows. How can I solve this out?

OBS: The parameters referred to the spreadsheet 'Hélices_0 - Teste' are fixed (F4).

Comment: [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/Excel.Range.Offset) may be useful in understanding how `Offset` works. You may also want to take the time to read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba)